# Python: Pandas dataframe merge duplicates for item start with '1'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is really weird as this only happen when merge two dataframe that has Stock start with '1'

```
>>> df_mo
    Stock  Momentum_
0     1A0       0.00
1     1A1       0.00
2     1A4       0.00
3     1B0       0.00
4     1B1       0.15
5     1B6       0.00
6     1C0       0.00
7     1C3       0.00
8     1C5       0.00
9     1D0       0.00
10    1D1       0.00
11    1D3      -0.50
12    1D4       0.00
13    1D5       0.00
14    1D8       0.00
15    40B      -0.15
16    40D       0.00
17    40E       0.00
18    40F       0.00
19    40N       0.00
20    40R       0.00
21    40S       0.15
22    40T       0.15
23    40U       0.00
24    40V       0.00
25    40W       0.00
26    41A       0.00
27    41B       0.15
28    41F       0.00
29    41H       0.00
..    ...        ...
757  T8JU       0.00
758   T8V       0.00
759   TQ5       0.00
760  TS0U       0.00
761   U04       0.00
762   U06       0.00
763   U09       0.00
764   U10       0.00
765   U11       0.00
766   U13       0.00
767   U14       0.00
768   U6C       0.00
769   U77       0.00
770   U96       0.00
771   U9E       0.00
772  UD1U       0.00
773   UD2       0.00
774   UV1       0.00
775   V01       0.00
776   V03       0.00
777   W05       0.00
778   Y03       0.00
779   Y06       0.00
780   Y35       0.00
781   Y45       0.00
782   Y92       0.00
783   Z25       0.00
784   Z59       0.00
785   Z74       0.00
786   Z77       0.00
[787 rows x 2 columns]

>>> df_active
    Stock  Active
0     1A0    0.35
1     1A1    0.35
2     1A4   -0.35
3     1B0    0.50
4     1B1   -0.35
5     1B6   -0.35
6     1C0    0.50
7     1C3   -0.35
8     1C5    0.35
9     1D0   -0.50
10    1D1    0.50
11    1D3    0.35
12    1D4   -0.50
13    1D5    0.35
14    1D8   -0.50
15    40B    0.35
16    40D   -0.35
17    40E   -0.50
18    40F   -0.35
19    40N    0.35
20    40R    0.25
21    40S    0.50
22    40T    0.50
23    40U    0.35
24    40V    0.35
25    40W   -0.35
26    41A   -0.35
27    41B   -0.35
28    41F    0.50
29    41H   -0.50
..    ...     ...
757  T8JU    0.35
758   T8V    0.35
759   TQ5   -0.50
760  TS0U    0.50
761   U04    0.50
762   U06    0.50
763   U09   -0.50
764   U10    0.50
765   U11    0.50
766   U13   -0.35
767   U14    0.50
768   U6C   -0.25
769   U77   -0.25
770   U96   -0.50
771   U9E   -0.50
772  UD1U    0.50
773   UD2   -0.50
774   UV1   -0.35
775   V01   -0.50
776   V03    0.50
777   W05    0.25
776   V03    0.50
778   Y03    0.20
779   Y06   -0.35
780   Y35    0.35
781   Y45   -0.25
782   Y92    0.50
783   Z25    0.50
784   Z59    0.50
785   Z74   -0.35
786   Z77    0.50
[787 rows x 2 columns]
```

But when I merged these two dataframe, the Stock that start with '1' all duplicated for 3 times extra.

```
>>> pd.merge(df_mo,df_active,how='outer',on='Stock')
    Stock  Momentum_  Active
11    1A4       0.00   -0.35
0     1A0       0.00    0.35
1     1A0       0.00    0.35
2     1A0       0.00    0.35
3     1A0       0.00    0.35
4     1A1       0.00    0.35
5     1A1       0.00    0.35
6     1A1       0.00    0.35
7     1A1       0.00    0.35
8     1A4       0.00   -0.35
9     1A4       0.00   -0.35
10    1A4       0.00   -0.35
11    1A4       0.00   -0.35
12    1B0       0.00    0.50
13    1B0       0.00    0.50
14    1B0       0.00    0.50
15    1B0       0.00    0.50
16    1B1       0.15   -0.35
17    1B1       0.15   -0.35
18    1B1       0.15   -0.35
19    1B1       0.15   -0.35
20    1B6       0.00   -0.35
21    1B6       0.00   -0.35
22    1B6       0.00   -0.35
23    1B6       0.00   -0.35
24    1C0       0.00    0.50
25    1C0       0.00    0.50
26    1C0       0.00    0.50
27    1C0       0.00    0.50
28    1C3       0.00   -0.35
29    1C3       0.00   -0.35
..    ...        ...     ...
787  T8JU       0.00    0.35
788   T8V       0.00    0.35
789   TQ5       0.00   -0.50
790  TS0U       0.00    0.50
791   U04       0.00    0.50
792   U06       0.00    0.50
793   U09       0.00   -0.50
794   U10       0.00    0.50
795   U11       0.00    0.50
796   U13       0.00   -0.35
797   U14       0.00    0.50
798   U6C       0.00   -0.25
799   U77       0.00   -0.25
800   U96       0.00   -0.50
801   U9E       0.00   -0.50
802  UD1U       0.00    0.50
803   UD2       0.00   -0.50
804   UV1       0.00   -0.35
805   V01       0.00   -0.50
806   V03       0.00    0.50
807   W05       0.00    0.25
808   Y03       0.00    0.20
809   Y06       0.00   -0.35
810   Y35       0.00    0.35
811   Y45       0.00   -0.25
812   Y92       0.00    0.50
813   Z25       0.00    0.50
814   Z59       0.00    0.50
815   Z74       0.00   -0.35
816   Z77       0.00    0.50
[817 rows x 3 columns]
```

As the merge result make it more row. I have many dataframe that need to merge and thus this end up much more rows that it supposed to.

The code actually works well for number start with '4' or any other number or string. It just has some issues for number start with '1'.

How to make it only able to merge correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem you have duplicated values in `Stock` column, duplicates starts with `1`.

You can check it by:

```
print (df_mo[df_mo['Stock'].duplicated(keep=False)])
print (df_active[df_active['Stock'].duplicated(keep=False)])
```

Solution is remove duplicates. E.g.:

```
df_active = df_active.drop_duplicates('Stock')
df_mo= df_mo.drop_duplicates('Stock')
```

Sample:

```
print (df_mo)
  Stock  Momentum_
0   1A0        0.0
0   1A0        0.0
0   1A0        0.0
1   1A1        0.0
2   1A4        0.0
3   1A4        0.0

print (df_active)
  Stock  Active
0   1A0    0.35
0   1A0    0.55
1   1A1    0.35
2   1A4   -0.35
3   1A4    0.50

df = pd.merge(df_mo,df_active,how='outer',on='Stock')
print (df)
   Stock  Momentum_  Active
0    1A0        0.0    0.35
1    1A0        0.0    0.55
2    1A0        0.0    0.35
3    1A0        0.0    0.55
4    1A0        0.0    0.35
5    1A0        0.0    0.55
6    1A1        0.0    0.35
7    1A4        0.0   -0.35
8    1A4        0.0    0.50
9    1A4        0.0   -0.35
10   1A4        0.0    0.50
```

---

```
print (df_mo[df_mo['Stock'].duplicated(keep=False)])
  Stock  Momentum_
0   1A0        0.0
0   1A0        0.0
0   1A0        0.0
2   1A4        0.0
3   1A4        0.0

print (df_active[df_active['Stock'].duplicated(keep=False)])
  Stock  Active
0   1A0    0.35
0   1A0    0.55
2   1A4   -0.35
3   1A4    0.50
```

---

```
df_active = df_active.drop_duplicates('Stock')
df_mo= df_mo.drop_duplicates('Stock')

df = pd.merge(df_mo,df_active,how='outer',on='Stock')
print (df)
  Stock  Momentum_  Active
0   1A0        0.0    0.35
1   1A1        0.0    0.35
2   1A4        0.0   -0.35
```